# CodeIgniter form_error returns error message and set_value returns nothing on first page load

Tags: php, codeigniter

When using CodeIgniter's Form Validation class, the `form_errors` in the view always show the error messages. Also, using the `set_value` method never populates the field with the correct values unless there's no validation against it.

I have extended the form_validation class, but only to add a new method that I needed and removing the code entirely does not make a difference.

The code for my controller is:

```
function test() {
    $data['title'] = 'My title';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('form', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('form', $data);
    }
}
```

The code for my view is:

```
echo form_open(current_url()).
     form_error('title').
     form_label('Title', 'title').
     form_input(array('name' => 'title', 'id' => 'title'), set_value('title', $title)).
     form_label('Other', 'other').
     form_input(array('name' => 'other', 'id' => 'other'), set_value('other', 'test')).
     form_submit('submit', 'Update').
     form_close();
```

What I expect is that there are no error messages show, the first input field would have the text 'My title' and the second field would have the text 'other'. If I submitted the forms, then they would show the posted values.

In reality, I always get an error message saying that the first field is required, the first field is always empty when the page loads and the second field is filled correctly with the text 'other'.

If I fill in both/either of the fields and post the form, the fields are returned with the post data, which is correct. I cannot see what I am doing wrong and any help is appreciated.

Comment: you get error when submit first field empty?

Comment: The error shows before any form has been submitted.

Comment: try calling the form in a separate method that just shows the form.

Comment: If I comment out the validation rules, it works as expected, but then then my entire form has no validation against it. I could make it so that the validation rules are only applied on post, but according to the documentation, I shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: have you tried loading the code without passing data into it? instead of `$this->load->view('form', $data);` try `$this->load->view('form');`

Comment: @aashnisshah no difference excluding this variable, the form validation is always run on page load and shows errors/fails to populate the field.

Comment: Form validation is only executed if the HTTP request coming in is POST, so, somehow when you access the controller action it seems that it is being treated as POST instead of GET which is what you'll request if going through the browser. Are you doing something else on the constructor of your controller? (or the base controller if it is inherited from such)

Comment: Nothing to do with POST or GET, I've just tried again with a clean install of CodeIgniter and the issue seems to be gone. Comparing files, there is literally no difference in code, but all is OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your code in the file

/system/libraries/form_validation.php

line 77 should be

```
if (count($_POST) == 0)
```

instead of

```
if (!isset($_POST))
```

Comment: I've extended MY_Form_validation to handle this, and the validation works correctly (still don't understand why this doesn't work), but `set_value()` still does not populate the field correctly.

Comment: Also, this fix also stops form validation working when there are no failures after POST data is sent. If there's an error, it works as expected, but not when there are no errors.

Comment: Looks like some changes were made to the core somehow. I extended the classes so not sure how the changes happened, but with a new copy of CodeIgniter, things are working much better now. Thanks. Will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code i hope it will be help to you.
Controller

```
function test()
     {
         $this->load->library('form_validation');       
            $data['title1'] = 'My title';
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('form', $data);
            } else {
                $this->load->view('form', $data);
            }
    }
```

and form

```
<?php 
echo form_open('CONTROLLERNAME/test').
     form_error('title').
     form_label('Title', 'title').
     form_input(array('name' => 'title', 'id' => 'title'), set_value('title', $title1)).
     form_label('Other', 'other').
     form_input(array('name' => 'other', 'id' => 'other'), set_value('other', 'test')).
     form_submit('submit', 'Update').
     form_close();
?>
```

Here you pass the data of title in view and fields name is also title so every time form fields of title print value.